# Why is Jasmine not waiting for my promises to complete?

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, jasmine

I am using the FileSystem API to produce a directory with 2 entries inside it that I need to use as input for a test I want to run. The problem is that Jasmine does not wait for the promise to resolve before running the test so it fails. I have used the async wrapper but it does not seem to make a difference.

Does anyone know why it is failing?

```
describe('traverseDirectory() method', () => {

let directoryToTraverse;
let entries;

beforeEach(async(() => {

    console.log('beforeEach test');


    const file1 = createBlob(['<a id="a"><b id="b">Hello A</b></a>'], {type: 'text/html'});
    const file2 = createBlob(['<a id="b"><b id="b">Hello B</b></a>'], {type: 'text/html'});

    function createFile(fs: any, fileName: string, blob: Blob): Promise<any> {

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        fs.root.getFile(fileName, {create: true}, (fileEntry) => {

          fileEntry.createWriter((fileWriter) => {
            fileWriter.onwriteend = (e) => {
              resolve(fileEntry);
              // @ts-ignore
            };

            fileWriter.write(blob);
          });
        });
      });
    }

    function moveToDirectory(directoryEntry: any, fileEntry: any): void {
      fileEntry.moveTo(directoryEntry);
    }

    function createDirectory(fs: any, name: string): Promise<any> {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.root.getDirectory(name, {create: true}, (directoryEntry) => {
          resolve(directoryEntry);
        }, errorHandler);
      });

    }


    function errorHandler(err: any): void {
      console.log('ERROR:', err);
    }


    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      function onInitFs(fs: any): void {
        createDirectory(fs, 'Documents').then((directoryEntry) => {

          const f1 = createFile(fs, 'File1.html', file1);
          const f2 = createFile(fs, 'File2.html', file2);
          Promise.all([f1, f2]).then((createdEntries) => {
            createdEntries.forEach((entry) => {
              moveToDirectory(directoryEntry, entry);

            });
            directoryToTraverse = directoryEntry;
            console.log('Finished setup');
            resolve();
          });
        });

      }

      // @ts-ignore
      window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024 * 1024, onInitFs, errorHandler);

    });

  })
);

it('should run', async(() => {

  console.log('Running the test');
  service.traverseDirectory(directoryToTraverse).then(res => {
    entries = res;
  });

  expect(directoryToTraverse).toEqual(entries);


}));

});
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the async function use then? I thought it forced promises to be run in a sort of sandbox environment that waited for promises to complete

Comment: Btw, instead of calling `errorHandler` you should always call `reject`.

Comment: I believe you are thinking of async/await from here:  https://javascript.info/async-await

Whereas I am using async from angular/core/testing: https://angular.io/api/core/testing/async

Comment: Oh. Right. I missed the extra parenthesis.

Comment: Can you clarify what is exactly the part that is failing here? Which promise is not being awaited on? It's for me to understand where you have your issue

Comment: _"Why is Jasmine not waiting for my promises to complete?"_ - because she's had enough of you and your promises and ran off with Aladdin.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-testing-async-fakeasync

You can use `fixture.whenStable` for when all promises have resolved then proceed with the tests but I think in your case, you should put the expect inside of the then because the expect is going to run before what happens inside of the then due to promise's asynchronous nature.

```
it('should run', async(() => {

  console.log('Running the test');
  service.traverseDirectory(directoryToTraverse).then(res => {
    entries = res;
    console.log(entries); // make sure you see this line
    expect(directoryToTraverse).toEqual(entries);
  });
}));
```